Does Hashem still consider the past sins of a convert which did Teshuvah?
Shalom,
As a prospective convert, who learns Moshe Maimonides teachings, I am confused about the language he uses about responsibility for the past actions. Specifically, if a Catholic Christian leaves his old religion and converts to Judaism, what is his / her liability for acts considered sins in Judaism but are acceptable and even supported by his old faith?
In particular, how is it interpreted in the specific case of a convert who tried in the past spreading his / her old religion among other people, but now feels that his or her efforts would be inappropriate in Judaism? Should one try doing something regarding those people who he brought to Catholicism?
Is there mercy for such a person, which one can find in the stories of Nebuzaradan and of Menashe, for one who is really honest, although has guilt but whishes to repair one's faults and desires to love Hashem and the Jewish people?
Thank you for all your answers.

Welcome to Me Yodeya! This site is different from other sites, and it's policy is not to give personal halachic decisions. There are some good genuine questions that you have in your first posting here. Please try modifying it so that it does not have personal info. You mention that you are in contact with a rabbi. He certainly can guide you or suggest someone who can help with personal halachic (legal) decisions, as all of us do.

@YDJ I am not a fan of editing an obviously personal question to make it impersonal, but sometimes I've seen it done. Either way, if you want to edit it, just make it into a direct, single sentence question - e.g. "what power does teshuva have over sins committed before one converted to Judaism, such as sins of idolatry or witchcraft". I won't vote to open but others might
